# During database updates the schema of any module could be out of date

Tags: 7, updating

I try to well understand [Update versions API functions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/group/update_api/7).
I globally understand the concept, but I have some doubt.

In fact Drupal makes no verification about the N version number use in the name of a simplified function ***_update_N_mymodule_my_function()***. N can be what ever we want (even a string) ? 
More, even the whole name of function can be named in fact e.g "toto()" ? Drupal makes no verification, and names used for functions simplified are just for convenience. Correct ?

Comment: Look at the bottom of the page for a bunch of examples - see the list of functions whose name start with an underscore? Those are simplified versions of existing core functions, written specifically for a single update, presumably because a change to the original API function at some point would have caused that update to fail if the original had been used. Make sense?

Comment: @Clive, ok and it's mean that in fact Drupal makes no verification about the N version number use in the name of a simplified function _update..N...(). In fact, N can be what ever we want (even a string) ? More even the whole name of function can be named in fact e.g "toto()"  ? Drupal makes no verification. Correct ?

Comment: Correct, the name of the function isn't validated anywhere. The convention does make it pretty clear what the purpose of the function is though, and protect it from collisions later on. Wouldn't be the worst idea to adopt it IMO

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not correct. You cannot use a string as update version for a update hook, or Drupal will not recognize it as update hook.
For the other functions that aren't hook, Drupal doesn't check their name follow a schema, since Drupal is not going to call them. The only non-hook functions Drupal calls are those functions referred in some data structure returned to Drupal, or those functions whose names match a form ID followed by *_validate* or *_submit*, which could be used as form validation or submission handlers.

See the code executed from [`drupal_get_schema_versions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21install.inc/function/drupal_get_schema_versions/7), in particular the following one.

```
// Prepare regular expression to match all possible defined hook_update_N().
$regexp = '/^(?P<module>.+)_update_(?P<version>\d+)$/';
$functions = get_defined_functions();
// Narrow this down to functions ending with an integer, since all
// hook_update_N() functions end this way, and there are other
// possible functions which match '_update_'. We use preg_grep() here
// instead of foreaching through all defined functions, since the loop
// through all PHP functions can take significant page execution time
// and this function is called on every administrative page via
// system_requirements().
foreach (preg_grep('/_\d+$/', $functions['user']) as $function) {
  // If this function is a module update function, add it to the list of
  // module updates.
  if (preg_match($regexp, $function, $matches)) {
    $updates[$matches['module']][] = $matches['version'];
  }
}
```

A function name like `mymodule_update_toto()` would not match `/_\d+$/`, so it would be discarded immediately; a function name like `mymodule_test_001()` would not match `/^(?P<module>.+)_update_(?P<version>\d+)$/`, so it would be discarded on the second round.
The same is true for a function name like `_update_N_mymodule_my_function()`: Since it doesn't end with a number, it would be discarded at the first round. `_update_mymodule_my_function_N()` would be discarded on the second round, since `_update_` is no after the module name (so it doesn't match `/^(?P<module>.+)_update_(?P<version>\d+)$/`).

Comment: thks for your answer, but my question wasn't about hook_update_N but about _update_N_mymodule_my_function().

Comment: The answer doesn't change: The function name doesn't start with the module name, and it doesn't end with a number, so it would be descarded.

Comment: I don't think that drupal_get_schema_versions() is called for checking _update_N_mymodule_my_function(), because _update_7200_mymodule_my_function is discarded too when i use the regex

Comment: `drupal_ger_schema_versions()` is called to get an array of updates for a module, and it will not consider your function as update hook. You said _Drupal makes no verification about the N version number use_ and that is false; Drupal checks the update hook contains a number at the end of its name, so you cannot use a name like `_update_7200_mymodule_my_function()` for an hook update because Drupal will not consider it as hook update.

Comment: I never talk about hook_update_N. I said : "In fact Drupal makes no verification about the N version number **use(d) in the name of a simplified function _update_N_mymodule_my_function()**"

Comment: It is a private function, and it is not a hook; Drupal doesn't make any verification of such function names.

Comment: Ok, that was my misunderstanding about such functions whose names contain N version. Now, we understand each other! thks